# SalesForce.com Display image in S-Control

Tags: html, crm, salesforce

I need to display an image in an S-Control is SFDC.  I would like to be able to reference a static resource like `<apex:image url="{!$Resource.TestImage}" />`, but that only works in VisualForce pages and I have to modify and existing S-Control (switching to VF is not an option).

What's the best way to accomplish this, so frustrated with the general lack of documentation and hackishness of SFDC development.

Thanks all

Comment: FYI <img src="https://cs3.salesforce.com/resource/[someCrazyNumber]/[MyResourceName]" /> seems to work, not sure if [someCrazyNumber] can change?

Comment: It can change when you'll reupload the resource or switch environment (i.e. you'll deploy from sandbox to production env. -> oops). But easy to fix as you can edit S-Controls on the fly on production. You could also upload images to Documents tab and use them in `<img>` tag. In this case "crazy number" will be the ID of generated record and further updates of image will not change this number.

Comment: @eyescream - would you mind entering an answer with Documents example and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload your image to Documents tab and later use normal `<img>` tag to display it on S-Controls, Visualforce pages and email templates (last one - if this will be an "externally available image"). The generated URL to view it will look somewhat like

https://c.na7.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015A0000001IFxZ

(my test org sits at na7.salesforce.com instance and the last part is gnerated object's ID)